# IPC - Message queue

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, named-pipes

Lets say I have a simple calculater.exe application. I launch 2 instances of it  ( Cal_1  , Cal_2 ). I want Cal_1 to send message to Cal_2 . I am thinking using message queue is a good option , any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to send commands between two applications you have written, or between two existing apps that you have no control over?  If it's the latter, then I don't know what to tell you, other than tying into the messages in the Windows API or using the UI Automation framework.

If the two applications are apps that you have written, you can use .NET Remoting with an IPC channel.

More information is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: BTW, .NET Remoting with IPC is common when you have a Windows Service that needs to be controlled by a separate UI front-end application.  It would be the same exact concept for having two UI's control each other.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [ZeroMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall) messaging framewwork in request-reply or publish-subscribe mode. It's easy to use and it has [C#](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3aclr) bindings via NuGet.